# Reducing complex arithmetic to a three-variable polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, logic, ring-theory, complex-numbers, universal-algebra

This was *not* the question I wanted to ask originally - I've asked the right version [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4116508/is-there-a-two-variable-polynomial-capturing-complex-arithmetic).

---

This is a very small special case of [this question of Gregory Nisbet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115344/is-it-possible-to-formulate-the-theory-of-rings-using-a-3-place-relation). Say that a polynomial $p$ with complex coefficients **captures the complex field** iff addition and multiplication of complex numbers are first-order definable in the structure $(\mathbb{C};p)$. For example, the polynomial $$q(x,y,z,w)=(x+y)z-w$$ captures the complex field:

- We can define $0$ as the unique $t$ such that for all $x,y$ we have $q(x,y,t,t)=t$.
- We can then define multiplication as $ab=q(a,0,b,0)$.
- We can define $1$ as the unique $s$ such that for all $x$ we have $q(x,0,s,0)=x$.
- Finally, this lets us define addition as $a+b=q(a,b,1,0)$.

---

Following Gregory Nisbet's above-linked question, I'm curious if we can do better, at least as far as the number of variables is concerned:

> Is there a polynomial in $3$ variables which captures the complex field?

*I've removed some embarrassingly silly guesswork; see the edit history if curious.*

Comment: I have a [sort-of solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4116448) to my original question using $\exp$ and joining some unrelated equations together via or. Is or-ing polynomials acceptable here?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet That would **not** be acceptable here. But see Troposphere's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost already have a solution: Just ignore the $w$ input to your polynomial.

That is, set $f(x,y,z) = (x+y)z$, and define

- $0$ is the unique $t$ such that for all $x, y$ we have $f(x,y,t)=t$.
- $1$ is the unique $u$ such that for all $x$ we have $f(x,0,u)=x$.
- $x+y$ is $f(x,y,1)$.
- $xy$ is $f(x,0,y)$.

Comment: ... Wow, that's embarrassing. Great!

Comment: Holy *cow* I'm having a stupid day today. *And* that ruins the original motivation for this question! Derp.