# Is there a two-variable polynomial capturing complex arithmetic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, logic, complex-numbers, field-theory, universal-algebra

My question is whether there is a polynomial in two variables which, in a precise sense, encodes the ring structure of $\mathbb{C}$:

> Is there a two-variable complex polynomial $p(x,y)$ such that complex addition and multiplication are each first-order definable in the structure $(\mathbb{C}; p)$?

This is related to [this question of Gregory Nisbet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115344/is-it-possible-to-formulate-the-theory-of-rings-using-a-3-place-relation). I [earlier asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4116435/28111) the *three*-variable version of this question ... because counting is hard and I didn't realize that a *three*-variable function corresponds to a *four*-ary relation. This was the question I meant to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $p(x,y)=x^2+y$.  We can define $0$ as the unique $a$ such that $p(a,y)=y$ for all $y$.  We can then define squaring as $x^2=p(x,0)$, and then define addition as $x+y=p(z,y)$ where $z$ is any element such that $z^2=x$.  Once we have addition and squaring, we can define multiplication since $xy$ is the unique element such that $xy+xy=(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2$.

This construction works more generally in any reduced commutative ring in which every element has a square root and $2$ is not a zero divisor.  I imagine some of these assumptions can be removed or modified by tweaking the construction, but I suspect a different idea would be needed to get a polynomial that works without some very strong assumption similar in spirit to "every element has a square root".

Comment: Very nice! Two questions: what does "reduced" mean and what was wrong with your original answer (at a glance it looks right and more general)?

Comment: "Reduced" means that $x^2=0$ implies $x=0$.  My original answer had the very dumb mistake of taking $p(x,y)-xy$ before it knew how to subtract.

Comment: Ah I missed that, thanks!

Comment: Thinking back to Gregory Nisbet's original question, do you have any ideas on that (specifically, the phrasing: "is there a single three-variable first-order formula $\varphi$ in the language of rings such that if $\mathcal{R}=(R;+,\times)$ is a ring then $+$ and $\times$ are definable in $(R; \varphi^\mathcal{R})$")? I started out expecting a negative answer, but now I''m swinging the other way. I certainly have no clue how to try for a negative answer!

Comment: How about something like $z=xy\vee z=x+y$?  It seems quite plausible to me that you could untangle the two cases to recover addition and multiplication separately.

Comment: I did think about that but couldn't get it to work. But, I think the last few hours have clearly established that I'm Not Good At Rings.

Comment: For a polynomial that captures complex arithmetic, it's pretty simple!